# How can I generate and validate random IDs using the Saudi ID format?

Tags: php

I need to generate random IDs that validate against the criteria for Saudi IDs shown in this question:

[Saudi Iqama/National Identity number field validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185182/saudi-iqama-national-identity-number-field-validation)

I've tried the following code:

```
$random_numbers = [];
while(count($random_numbers) < 1000000000){
    do  {
    $random_number = mt_rand(1000000000,9000000000);  
     
}

while (in_array($random_number, $random_numbers));{
$type = substr ( $random_number, 0, 1 );
if($type != 2 && $type != 1 ) break;

$sum = 0;
for( $i = 0 ; $i<10 ; $i++ ) {
  if ( $i % 2 == 0){
    $ZFOdd = str_pad ( ( substr($random_number, $i, 1) * 2 ), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
    $sum += substr ( $ZFOdd, 0, 1 ) + substr ( $ZFOdd, 1, 1 );
  }else{
    $sum += substr ( $random_number, $i, 1 );
  }
}
return $sum%10 ? break : echo  $random_number;


 ----------



echo "<br>";
$random_numbers[] = $random_number;}
}
```

Comment: What is the intended format?

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense; what with the `return` and the `{` on the second while?

Comment: @Steven want  return the generate number that match with format

this format i use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185182/saudi-iqama-national-identity-number-field-validation

Comment: @user3783243 

this is format i used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185182/saudi-iqama-national-identity-number-field-validation

Comment: So you want to create a random `10` digit number where the first number is `1|2`?

Comment: @Steven yes and it correct when put it in the formal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** *I'm not 100% sure on the validation required etc. for Saudi ID numbers and have only briefly looked at the answers supplied in the linked question*

---

Okay, so, my understanding is that you need to generate a *random id* that:

1. Matches the pattern/format:

   ```
   [12]\d{9}
   ```
2. Validates against the criteria show in the linked question:

   - [Saudi Iqama/National Identity number field validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185182/saudi-iqama-national-identity-number-field-validation)

To do this we need to create a couple of functions; one to generate IDs and one to validate the IDs against the given criteria.

**Generate the ID**

Simply generating an ID is simple enough. We can use the `random_int` function in PHP with a loop. If we enclose the code to generate the ID inside of a `do...while...` loop then we can execute the code and validate the ID repeatedly until we get a valid one.

```
function getRandomSaudiId() : int
{
    do {
        $saudiId = (string) random_int(1,2);
        for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
            $saudiId .= random_int(0,9);
        }
    } while(validateSaudiId($saudiId) === false);

    return (int) $saudiId;
}
```

**Validate the ID**

Note: we convert to `string` so that we can access the numbers based on their index.

```
function validateSaudiId(string $id) : bool
{
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
        if( $i % 2 ){
            // Even number
            $sum += $id[$i];
        }
        else{
            //Odd number
            $increment = $id[$i] * 2;
            while($increment > 9){
                $increment = (string) $increment;
                $increment = $increment[0] + $increment[1];
            }
            $sum += $increment;
        }
    }

    $sum = (string) $sum;

    return ($sum[1] == $id[9] || $id[9] == (10 - $sum[1])) ? true : false;
}
```

**Example use**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) var_dump(getRandomSaudiId());

/*

Output:

int(2933617506)
int(2409806096)
int(1072585118)
int(2891306413)
int(1810304558)
int(2591965856)
int(1363032527)
int(1031823269)
int(1265954048)
int(2498099472)
int(1134172537)

*/
```